# 500 error on the first request deploying in production an angular spring-boot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, deployment, production-environment

I deploy an Angular/springboot application in production`enter code here`

When I start the java backend part (runing as jar) it seems that everything works because a sql script was loaded and there is a scheduled task that runs at 6:30
So I deployed also the Angular front end part with nginx.

When I hit the url, the index.html is displayed and css and js loading requests related to that file run without any error.
But the first authentification angular request http://myrequest/api/principal return a 500 error.
That url hit the following method

```
@GetMapping("/principal")
public CustomUserDetails getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (CustomUserDetails) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal()).getPrincipal();
}
```

That error is not logged in the log of springboot (backend part). In contrast In the front end part the message is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Dw: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","url":"http://myrequest/api/principal","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://myrequest/api/principal: 500 Internal Server Error","error":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an internal error or\nmisconfiguration and was unable to complete\nyour request.</p>\n<p>Please contact the server administrator at \n department@mycompany.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred,\n and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>\n<p>More information about this error may be available\nin the server error log.</p>\n</body></html>\n"}
    at T (polyfills-es2015.8937eca6b008719608f2.js:1)
    at T (polyfills-es2015.8937eca6b008719608f2.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.8937eca6b008719608f2.js:1
    at l.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.8937eca6b008719608f2.js:1)
```

How can I debug this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, while I was deploying on nginx server with port 80, the solution was to deploy on port 8080. Thank you for your help